# Report Generation using Large Timeseries Data without leveraging Spark or Hadoop

Tags: python, pandas, hadoop, pyspark

Background: We have an old school CentOS7 VM that takes care of most of our reporting.
I need to figure out a way to write a python script that will generate a daily report from the the previous day's event records and push the final report to a SQL DB. (Without leveraging spark or hadoop).

The expected input is ~900 csv records/sec or ~77Mil/Day (~30GB). The csv file rollover is configurable on either size or time. So the entire input data is divided into smaller chunks of CSVs.

I came up with the following ***approach***:

> Read each new csv file, aggregate the data and store it in parquet format every n minutes.
> Once every 24hrs Read all the parquet files and generate the final report.

I read that parquet provides better compression and aggregation used together with pandas.

Would it be significant ? I'd like to know if there's something i can do to improve efficiency?
I dont mind if its a long running process. It can take a long time as well. All I want is the eventual output and for it not to hog all the memory.

Comment: Try using DuckDB